# touchUpInside effect for UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uibarbuttonitem

When `left/rightBarButtonItem` of `UIBarButtonItem` is tapped, I do not see the touchUpInside effect. i.e. the color of the button should change. Do I need to implement something here?

I am not able to change the color when I put my finger on the right bar button. I do not see any property called background color on `UIBarButtonItem`. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant change the color of the `UIBarButtonItem`, you need to set the `Tint` of the `UINavigationController` that the button is on.

The UIBarButtonItem will inherit the Tint color of the NavBar. You can alternatively change the `UIBarButtonStyle` to **`UIBarButtonSystemItemDone`** to make the button a darker color of the navBar's Tint.

Also, the `UIBarButtonItem` does not have a `touchUpInside` method, you can override it's action by `setAction:`.

Here are some of your options for `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];

    /* make the back button an image */
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage.png"]];

    /* change the title for child views */
    [backButton setTitle:@"Go Back!"];

    /* tell the button to do something */
    [backButton setAction:@selector(doSomething:)];

    /* disable the button */
    [backButton setEnabled:NO];

    /* make this button the BACK button for nav controller */
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;

    /* create this button on the RIGHT side of the navBar */
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backButton;

[backButton release];
```

Answer (score 1):

UIBarButtonItem don't use touchUpInside, instead they only have the target and action to define when they are activated.

Comment: I got it but I am not able to change the color when I put my finger on the button. I do not see any property called background color on UIBarButtonItem. How to achieve this?